# How Would Metabolism Work For A Zombie?

Tags: science-based, biology, zombies

In this story I am planning to write, zombies are real! A bacterium has resulted in the reactivation of the nervous system in recently dead humans, who will now seek to feed on the flesh of the living!!!!1 *(Insert dramatic & scary background music)*

Unfortunately since I'm trying to make these zombies possible in real life (So I won't get random stupid complaining from everyone on earth) they will have to get nutrients supplied somehow and find a way to release waste products like living people. Sadly since the heart of a zombie no longer pumps blood zombies would likely exhaust their reserved energy within a few hours or something and drop dead for real (like freshly killed fish flopping around until they stop after using up all their stored energy). Yeah I know this would still happen regardless but if we find a way around this small issue we can extend their lifespan for the story to continue!

QUESTION: HOW WOULD THE INFECTED CELLS FROM A ZOMBIE OBTAIN NUTRIENTS (or carry them to other infected cells like what blood would do) AND RELEASE WASTE PRODUCTS WHEN BOTH THE CIRCULATORY SYSTEM, SWEAT GLANDS (which we were discussing about earlier as a way for zombies to release ammonia & lactic acid) AND PRETTY MUCH EVERY OTHER BODILY FUNCTION EXCEPT FOR THE NERVOUS SYSTEM ARE DOWN? (I'm reminded of cockroaches while writting this, as they could survive weeks after being decapitated before starving because of the way blood is distributed around their body. Just something to get you started.)

Comment: I did not post this one in the sandbox first. Hope it does not get taken down... (prays to the almighty lord)

Comment: Also I am well aware that all of my questions are about zombies one way or the other. I am geinuely sorry for this so please don't get annoyed by it.

Comment: This seems to be unanswerable at present because: 1) You've not given us any criteria for us to judge a "best answer". 2) You've precluded science-based answers by the way it's written, then asked us for a science-based answer. 3) Cockroaches have a circulatory system, even with their heads cut off, so this part isn't really adding anything useful. Could you [edit].

Comment: @AngryMuppet Errr... about that... 1) I THINK I have outlined what I want here, anything that works goes for me. 2) I've asked this question because I wanted it to be science based but I don't know how. That's why I am here. 3) What I meant was something like "maybe the bacterium can form some kind of system like that but Im not sure" Sorry for the inconvenience, you can edit the question if you like

Comment: OK, then: 1) That's not how we work, we deal with questions that point to (have criteria that narrow it down to) a best answer. 2) That's fine, but unless they're microscopic zombies, their bodily processes will need a circulation. 3) See point 2. :)

Comment: Can you help me edit it?

Comment: You, the OP, should be the one to perform major edits to questions, not us. I get what you're after and it's tough. Zombies are fictional nightmare characters which turn up in fiction - but have little if anything to do with science. Asking a scientific question about them seems like it's doomed to start with unless you're at least a little familiar with how biological systems work - otherwise you're asking for a scientific explanation for the impossible, which no-one can give. (Well, to be fair, writers do sometimes write a load of gobbledegook, pseudoscientific-technobabble, off-topic here)

Comment: I don't know what kind of editing I should make without drifting away from my inital goal but maybe I should try a bit later

Comment: Now that you have answers, it'd be frowned on to make major changes to the question. That's why we have the sandbox so questions can be "perfected" before being posted and receiving unhelpful answers. (Or answers that lock it into not being able to be changed). Just do a bit of research into whatever you want to look at next, then ask another question in its own thread. Make sure to use the search facility to ensure that your question is not a duplicate too.

Comment: alright thanks :)

Comment: (And please go easy with the caps :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Human tissue necrotises fairly quickly if the circulatory system isn't working right. Once the heart stops pumping the body enters a decay state quite quickly if you don't take appropriate measures to prevent it: cooling or chemical preservation for instance. Individual cells may survive for a little longer out of random chance, but the buildup of metabolic byproducts will fairly quickly prevent cell function.

In other words, trying to get bodies to move under their own power more than a couple of hours after death and for more than a few minutes in total is probably not feasible. Especially not with a bacterial infection. Not even an engineered one. That's not how biology works.

Instead of trying to animate dead and decaying tissue, perhaps you could use it as a food source for some kind of creature that naturally lacks skeletal reinforcement but has evolved to use dead bodies not just as food but also for transport and as a weapon. For bonus points, let's make this as horrifying and nausea-inducing as possible because... well, zombies.

Since you seem to like bacteria, let's start with a bacterial infection as our first stage. Let's posit a bacterium that infects human bone marrow, messing with blood production and killing the human. As a metabolic byproduct the bacteria produces a particular acrasin, the signaling chemicals that amoeboid slime molds use to attract groups of amoeboid prior to forming a plasmoid body.

Once decay is well under way the acrasins are released from the bones, enticing swarms of amoeba from the environment. These form up around the bones and merge together to form a plasmoid around the bones, then proceeds to metabolize the abundant nutrients from the rotting corpse.

The thing about slime molds is that they are both mobile - albeit slowly - and are capable of producing quite interesting solutions to problems through natural optimization. They're a bit slow, but let's imagine that a series of mutations produces something a bit tougher and quicker. Now instead of just sitting quiescent and feasting, let's get our little slime mold to start moving around to find fresh corpses to snack on. As long as there's food and competition evolution can go to work, eventually refining a mobile entity that uses the bones of its' food as structural support while it roams about looking for the next meal. It wouldn't move like a human - which is kind of a bonus for zombies I think - and would probably just crawl or roll around initially, but give it time.

As the supply of corpses starts to thin, the final stage kicks in: gathering. The animated corpses are still full of bacteria that can infect other living creatures, producing a new crop of corpses to feed on. Shambling masses of rotting meat animated by bright yellow and red jelly growing around the bones begin to wander through the night, mindlessly tracing the metabolic byproducts of living creatures until they can come into contact with their soon-to-be new hosts.

And watch out for zombie rats, cats and dogs. The fur hides some of the more grotesque signs, and even accidental contact with claws or teeth can infect you. Head shots aren't going to help, since they don't exactly have brains, and shooting them in general is probably a bad idea. Perhaps [one of these](https://www.boringcompany.com/not-a-flamethrower) might help.

Oh, and when they "die", the plasmoid can disassemble into millions of amoeba again over a few minutes, starting the cycle over again when the next host corpse starts to smell.

(And yes, this is very similar to the fungal zombies from films like Cargo and games like Last of Us.)

---

(Updating to address comments)

> Oh my god this is so fucking gross... may consider it

You wanted zombie ideas, how could I not? :P

> 1. Having two different types of organisms cause zombification is a bit messy

Depending on your story needs the bacteria could be a bio-weapon that only incidentally produces acrasin. Or it could have been engineered that way in an attempt to hasten decomposition. Or it could be that the slime mold was created. They could just have readily arisen naturally, in the way that symbiotic, mutialistic and commensal organisms tend to do.

(Read up on nitrification where one sort of bacteria produces nitrites that another type of bacteria needs, processing it to nitrate.)

> 2. It sounds like the corpses will need a few days or something until they get up again as zombies, is there anyway we can shorten the zombification time to something like < 1hr?

If you're looking for something even vaguely science-compatible then an hour is far too short a time for a bunch of reasons. The amoeba don't move very quickly, plasmoid formation would take a couple of hours minimum, and the amoeba would have to tunnel through flesh to find the bones before plasmoidisation can even begin.

And don't forget that rigor mortis sets in between 2-4 hours after death on average and can last for many hours (15-25 normally, environment dependent). During this time the muscle cells are rigid due to ATP depletion locking the actin filaments, which stays that way until the proteins deteriorate. Our zombie slimes aren't going to be able to do anything with the bodies during this time other than try to hasten the cellular degradation.

That said, you could speed up the progression somewhat by having the bacteria produce heat through exothermic metabolism sufficient to raise the temperature of the bone marrow by a few degrees post mortem. This would speed up the ATP depletion, lysosome degradation and autolysis of the muscle proteins, shortening the rigor phase by a few hours and speeding up the initial decay. The residual heat could also increase the metabolic rate for the slime mold, which would be a nice bonus.

Or, since we're talking about zombies here and science is just a footnote in any good zombie story (A virus that makes zombies? I don't think Umbrella Corp ever even *heard* of science.) then it can be what you want it to be. You can load your amoeba up with necrotising enzymes so they can melt their way into the body, have the plasmoid release digestive enzymes to hasten the breakdown of the body, turn the metabolic rate of the plasmoid up to 11 and let rip. Call it 2 hours from dead to undead... fast enough?

Comment: This is real awesome but I have 2 problems: 1. Having two different types of organisms cause zombification is a bit messy, but maybe we can change it to some kind of bioweapon slime mold infection thingy that kills humans and turns them into zombies, then spreads spores by biting or releasing them into the air or something (like mushrooms?) 2. It sounds like the corpses will need a few days or something until they get up again as zombies, is there anyway we can shorten the zombification time to something like < 1hr? Sorry for being mouthy

Comment: An interesting example of this is the Mistwraiths and  Kandra in the Mistborn series by Brandon Sanderson. ("While Mistwraiths are simply gelatinous conglomerates of various creatures, kandra can actually absorb a body and take on all of its characteristics."). Sanderson is solidy fantasy though, he is way beyond the relm of earth science (although his worlds are hard science in their own way). May be a good example of how it can be done.

Comment: Damn. I can't understand all those scientific terms but it looks cool

Comment: @Hi0401 I figured all that from reading a few articles about slime molds an decomposition. Pretty sure I'm on a couple watch-lists by now. "Hey Google, what can you tell me about rigor mortis?"

Comment: *"Instead of trying to animate dead and decaying tissue, perhaps you could use it as a food source for some kind of creature that naturally lacks skeletal reinforcement but has evolved to use dead bodies not just as food but also for transport and as a weapon."* The scary thing here is that this exists. Cordyceps and sacculina. @Hi0401 check these out. The former is an ant-zombifying fungus that is the inspiration for *The Last of Us*. The second is a barnacle that zombifies crabs.

Comment: @Hi0401 just one more thing, I promise. Cordyceps zombifies ants not by controlling their neural tissue, but rather live muscle tissue directly. So it could hypothetically exert some control over the body of a brain dead ant. Now imagine that with humans.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw DAMN. So you would basically be forced into walking around eating everyone while being conscious enough to witness it all?

Comment: Just to be sure: Basically by the time the slime molds ate all the muscles and organs we get a walking skeleton that has goo like thingies for muscles that is really dumb and eats living people and animals, right? EDIT: Also I imagine that the slime molds would form a sack thingy to replace intestines (To store and break down the flesh the zombie ate. Ew)

Comment: @Hi0401 yes. It seems that infected ants even struggle for control but always lose at the end.

Comment: @Hi0401 Nah, these zombies don't actually need to eat: they bite to infect. Once the flesh has completely broken down the mold disassembles back to an amoeboid swarm that moves on to the next set of hosts.

Comment: Oh. I guess that would cut down their lifespan down a lot so I was thinking something more like photosyntheic moldy skeletons that can keep the apocalypse going forever. :) Very pleasant thought (vomits profusely)

Comment: @Hi0401 It could take weeks to deplete all the available nourishment though. Who knows? Oh, and you're welcome for any nighmare fuel I may have thrown your way :P

Comment: Okay I'm not recieving any new answers so I'm accepting this!! Yay

Comment: I feel like you only picked this one because of how much sheer disgust I managed to pack into it. It's a talent I guess :D

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way by far to achieve what you're asking is for your zombies to be made out of *living*, rather than dead, people. Have your bacterium infect the  nervous system, wrecking the more abstract brain functions, but leaving the body's metabolism working.

Your zombies still need to eat and drink, and are alive, but they can behave as zombie-ish as you like.

Re-animating dead people is really hard, for several reasons:

- To keep them going, you need their metabolism running. That's a really complicated biochemical and biomechanical system, with loads of subtle feedback loops. Restarting "just part" of it won't work for long, and zombies that expire after a couple of hours aren't a big problem.
- Modern medicine allows replacing some of the biomechanical parts with artificial ones, and replacing the digestive system with intravenous feeding. Both of these things require a lot of external support equipment, and aren't practical for infectious zombies without any support being supplied.
- Dead people have died, in general terms, either because of physical injuries preventing their metabolisms working, or because their metabolisms have stopped working due to disease or age. Re-animating them using biology requires fixing whatever killed them, *while they are dead*.
- Their death deprives you of the ability to use their metabolism in the process of fixing them. You don't have any natural healing working, you can't use the circulatory system to distribute medicines through the body, and you can't monitor the metabolism to tell what's going on. Also, their cells are dying, meaning that you have very limited time before restarting their metabolism becomes *impossible*.

Comment: +1 because you’re right. But I want to point out that this has already been done in Maze Runner. [The Flare](https://mazerunner.fandom.com/wiki/The_Flare) is a virus that eats away at the human brain, turning humans into flesh-eating cannibalists.

Comment: @TheresaKay eh, if you ditch an idea because "_it was already done_" you'll either never do anything or you'll have to live the rest of your life in ignorance of what has been done before. 28 Days Later had living "zombies" with viral brain disease seven years earlier than the Maze Runner book, and Resident Evil was six years before that, and I doubt that was developed in a vacuum.

Comment: Maybe but if they were fully alive humans zombies won't be that scary anymore

Comment: @StarfishPrime it was not a call to drop the idea. Just that you should be aware what copying you may be accused of. Whatever you invent, the chance that someone did or tried it already is like 95% nowadays no matter how creative you are. This doesn't mean it's a bad idea, and especially "zombies but the base is still living" is such a naturally-coming idea that it deserves to occur more often in fiction

Comment: @StarfishPrime You may be right. I was only pointing it out because the OP keeps putting an emphasis on "doing something no one's done before" in their posts. Live-humans-with-rotting-brains has already been done. Dead-but-reanimated-humans that are biologically plausible have not (as far as I know).

Comment: @TheresaKay It's less about writing something new and more about proving a point :/

Answer (score 7):

This is a VERY interesting question. How do you define dead?

Seriously, this is a concept that modern medicine is redefining every year. In the last few decades it has been accepted that if your brain has suffered enough damage, you can be considered legally dead even if your heart is beating and you have reflexes. If you want to see some creepy stuff to go with your zombie research, look up the "Lazarus sign" - that's brain dead people moving their arms, sometimes even sitting up - yet they are for all practical purposes deceased. Depending on where in the world, they may or may not be legally deceased as well!

A brain dead person can be kept warm and with a metabolism for months when under life support. If you remove the constraint that your dead have their hearts stopped, then the bacteria could reanimate brain dead people.

Fungi would be more likely to restart or replace a dead brain, though, as the way some fungi are structured resembles a neural network. This would also bring your zombies closer to those of *The Last of Us*, which are the most realistic zombies I can think of in any fantastical literature.

Comment: I think I meant clinical death or something. Every function except for the brain, spinal cord and the neurons in the muscles are down

Comment: @Hi0401 that is the opposite of clinically dead. Because clinically dead means primarily that brain/spinal cord are inactive/dead and does NOT care about the rest

Comment: Oh... I thought that when your heart stops you are clinically dead and when your nervous system is gone then you are brain dead

Comment: @Hi0401 it used to be that if your heart stopped beating you would be considered clinically dead. But around the time CPR was invented that notion changed. In most places, as long as it is viable to restart your heart before irreversible brain damage is suffered, you may be considered alive. Also consider that you may need to stop someone's heart during some forms of heart surgery, with a machine temporarily taking the heart's role as a pump.

Comment: I blame my outdated information for this

Comment: Also a reason why this is not really ideal is that if the zombie relied on the heart you could just kill them by simply slicing off their arms and then waiting for them to bleed out

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is that the heart actually cannot stop because it causes so many insurmountable problems (bringing oxygen to cells, removing waste, dispatching digested stuff...). Any workaround to the blood circulation would be so slow that such zombies would remain still until they eventually decompose.

The only (sort of) scientific way I can imagine is that the zombies would be brain-dead, but otherwise healthy, and something would be controlling them: bacteria, virus, fungus, prion etc. Some diseases have strange effects on us. For example, rabies not only causes anger and aggression but also a fear of water (that has always fascinated me as a scientist; how a simple virus can create a phobia in its hosts).

In the movies 28 days later and 28 weeks later, the "zombies" are actually not dead but infected by a super-rabies virus. Yet, everyone consider these 2 films as zombie movies.

Comment: I'm looking for something that can make the typical "supposingly dead guy rises to eat everyone" type of zombie. Good try though, thank u

Comment: I'm sorry because I know it's too much to ask to get an answer I want from other normal people like me, but again thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

It would have to somehow cause some phenomenon with the "powerhouse of the cell".

Humans and most macroscopic organisms on planet Earth don't have alot of ATP (that chemical the mitochondria handle for us). Our mitochondria do enough for us to enable us to live the lives we want, fortunately... but they don't exactly suffer from too much ambition. We could, for instance, have lots more of the stuff and be (but for the inability to regulate temperature well enough) virtually superhuman.

The other cells in a corpse might be able to shuffle the whole thing around for much longer, if these microbes of yours could hack this system (perhaps bringing in "alien" mitochondria with much larger supplies, pinocytosis would allow for them to be absorbed by cells).

There are other challenges to be sure (ischemia, in the oxygen deprivation sense, not the "not getting enough blood sense", maybe hypoxia is a better word?), but those are also surmountable.

Your zombies would still have a shelf life, we're only extending it, not removing the expiration entirely. However, if this can resurrect a muscle, you run the risk of the same being possible in a brain. They might no longer act much like zombies. You definitely won't get the decomposition that makes zombies look like zombies.

Hell, it might even reboot life. Now the only thing left is the heartbeat, and if that happens, the cells can start functioning as they normally did.

I won't tell you how to write your story, but what makes zombies menacing, creepy, and interesting is that it's not just a virus/bacterium/cordyceps. Tell me what fears you harbor that makes you worry the dead would assault you if they could somehow return to ambulation. Do you lay awake at night thinking how you've squandered all the gifts your ancestors worked so hard to provide? That you've helped to wreck the planet? That you're unworthy of the place you've been allotted? To some degree or another, we all do. And our only relief is the people who would make us feel ashamed of how poorly we've lived life are already gone, no longer there to witness and embarrass us for our character defects.

It's not that there's this enemy we can't fight. We have nukes and spaceships. It's there are these former mentors, who seeing how we'll never do it right, have decided we shouldn't be allowed to do anything at all anymore.

The wicked are being punished. And they are us.

This is why the grimmest zombie shows are always those that are supernatural, and the ones that are the silliest try to explain it with science. But whatever you decide, good luck with your story and we hope to see it some day.

PS In one of the Peter Watts's stories, the aliens are born with all the ATP they'll ever need for a (long) life.

Answer (score 0):

I think all the other answers cover the bases I guess I just wanted to highlight... Dude, that's why zombies are a compelling fantasy concept and also don't exist. The point of a zombie is that they're dead but act alive. Your question is "how can my zombies act alive even though they're dead, and I know enough biology to know there's a contradiction here" and the answer is: good job, you've figured out the nature of life and the point of zombies. Living things move and do living things thanks to metabolism, their death is associated with the breakdown of that metabolism that makes it no longer possible for them to thermodynamically pull off doing living things, and zombies are fictional entities that combine the breakdown of death with the activity of life, and *those are biologically incompatible*.

I don't think you have a choice beyond either:

1. embracing your zombies as zombies - so forget about their metabolic functioning, zombies work in a world where life isn't about "metabolism" but is about "life force" which is only weakly associated with "the things living things do", i.e. you can have dead things with no "life force" doing the things living things do because those things are distinct from "life", OR you can have things that are structurally unable to do the things living things do nevertheless doing them because they have a "life force"
2. Making biologically realistic zombies, in which case they can't really be dead. I guess it really depends on how realistic you want your fiction to be at some point - for example I find the amoeba idea delightfully creepy but not realistic; I don't see why they'd coordinate to produce any coherent bodily movement at all. Like, you do need the limbs to move together in certain ways, you know, I don't think you could pull off anything beyond twitching without some perceptual feedbacks and cross-body coordination that micro-organisms that interact with the body as *an environment* instead of *a body* would have no way of evolving. And just moving a heavy body like ours probably requires more energy than you'd get just consuming said body. Still, they're alive. On the other end of the spectrum, "zombiism is just a kind of illness that impacts behavior" lacks a certain je ne sais quoi and you can still argue about how such an illness would work and how realistic it is for it to produce this or that specific zombie behavior (like, what are the cognitive implications of this or that action or ability). At the end of the day... if zombies were completely realistic then they'd be real, you know? So I think a big question in terms of answering your question is, how realistic are you hoping to get. Like, are you looking for good handwave ideas to sell a zombie concept that will come across as plausible to readers or have fun story implications, or do you think a scientifically plausible zombie is possible and that's what you want to write, or is there a very specific line of plausibility that would work for *you* and you need someone to sell *you* on a concept that fits with it...

A related question could be, what are the elements of "zombies" as a trope or concept that appeal to you and that you want to build your story around. That could do a lot to help decide how biologically plausible your zombies can afford to be or need to be, and conversely to what extent you need to or can shrug off biological plausibility altogether.